# order nodes using data-attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I have something like:

```
<ul>
   <li data-index="34"></li>
   <li data-index="2"></li>
   <li data-index="28"></li>
   <li data-index="6"></li>
   <li data-index="79"></li>
   <li data-index="1"></li>
</ul>
```

What is the quickest way to order the Dom using that data-index?

I am working with the bubble sort algorythm, but trying to find a quicker one.

(Pure javascript only, not jQuery)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Let's see your actual code otherwise it's impossible to benchmark in order to compare speeds.

Comment: "I am working with the bubble sort algorythm, but trying to find a quicker one."

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez: Actual code is crucial, your implementation may be different than someone else's. Have you actually checked the speed? http://jsperf.com/ maybe?

Comment: well, i left the code at the office and i didn't want to rewrite it without knowing if there was a better way. but thanks anyway

Comment: yes, it is so "difficult to tell what is being asked here" that i got 4 answers, all of them correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    lis = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    values = [],
    html = '';

for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
  values.push(lis[i].getAttribute('data-index'));
}

values = values.sort();
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('[data-index="' + values[i] + '"]')[0];
  html += el.outerHTML;
}
ul.innerHTML = html;
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz8wQ/)

Comment: How is this scaling with a large list? You let the browser construct objects internally, then serializing them to html text, and append that text into a larger and larger blob, which you finally let the browser parse and generate an element tree with. In which situation is this faster than only manipulating the dom, without having to go through html text (which involoves serializing and parsing)? Also, what happens if you have multiple lists which both have list itemes with the same "data-index" attribute?

Comment: this is a very specific solution for the html posted in this answer. if you have a better solution please post your answer. be more constructive.

Comment: I really urge anyone using this solution (currently marked as the "accepted answer") to think again if performance is of value. Do some benchmarking between this and pure dom manipulation solutions.

Comment: @gustafr: Agree, I created this quick jsPerf comparing this solution to mine (and yours which is pretty much the same) and the difference seems big enough to consider it. http://jsperf.com/sorting-dom-diff

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
var ul = document.getElementById( 'your ul element name' );
var arr = [ ];
for ( var i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i )
    arr.push( ul.children[ i ] );

arr.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return +a.getAttribute( 'data-index' ) - +b.getAttribute( 'data-index' );
} );

for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i )
    ul.appendChild( arr[ i ] );
```

Tell me if you need an explanation. The solution uses the built-in sort-mechanism on the Array object, which is probably rather fast.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit cumbersome, this does the trick quite nicely. Not sure the speed you're working with now, but this runs quite efficiently:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
var len = lis.length;
var indexs = [];
var obj = null;
var getByIndex = function(j){
    var li = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        li = lis[i];
        if(obj.getAttribute("data-index") == j) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return(li);
};
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    indexs.push(lis[i].getAttribute("data-index"));
}
indexs.sort(function(a, b){return(a - b);});
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    obj = getByIndex(indexs[i]);
    ul.appendChild(obj);
}
```

You can always optimize the code and what-have-you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should do. Not sure if it's the best performance, but it's short:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
    ul = items[0].parentNode;

[].slice.call( items ).sort(function( a,b ) {
  return a.getAttribute('data-index') - b.getAttribute('data-index');
}).forEach(function( item ) {
  ul.appendChild( item );
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/obasiq/1/edit

Comment: `[].slice` is elegant, I give you that. However, your forEach isn't standard afaict, so you'll need to loop over the values, which will end up being pretty much my answer. Interesting solution.

Comment: `forEach` is the standard nowadays but you can always use a polyfill for IE8-.